# How to I make a button clickable with HTML/CSS? It needs to be centered along with a title over an image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a button over an image that links to another page within the same site...I'm not very experienced with coding, but was able to find a few things online that helped me create what I needed. The main problem is that I haven't been able to make the button clickable, and am not sure where to insert the code that would link to the page I'm trying to point to.
Here's what I have so far - HTML:

```
<div class="albumimagewrap">
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/55d3ad3ee4b0adc8c326fe3f/t/57967922e6f2e14eefb8c308/1469479203582/Artboard+1.png?format=1000w" width="100%" height="100%">

<input type="h1" class="albumtitleimg" value="INNER CIRCLE">
<input type="p" class="albumtextimg" value="Debut Album Available Now">
<input type="button" class="albumbutton1" value="LISTEN">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.albumimagewrap {
position:relative;left:0;top:0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding-top:0%
}

.albumtitleimg {
display: block;
position:absolute;
margin: auto;
width: 250px;
top:20%;right:0%;left:0%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:transparent;
border: 0px;
}

.albumtextimg {
display: block;
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
width: 250px;
top:40%;right:0%;left:0%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
color:#ffffff;
background-color:transparent;
border: 0px;
}

.albumbutton1 {
display: block;
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
top:60%;right:0%;left:0%;
width: 240px;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color:transparent;
color: #ffffff;
border: 2px solid #BD9F6C;
}
```

I'm new here, so I can't upload images, but you can see the image/button here: [ZL Bandsite - Banner Img with Button](http://zachlarmer.bandzoogle.com/home#)

Any help is insanely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is, if clicking an element leads to a new page being loaded, use an anchor. So, in your case, I would use the following:

```
<a href="new-page.html" class="albumbutton1">
  <span>LISTEN</span>
</a>
```

Anchors naturally link to new pages, so there is no need to create additional JavaScript.

To center the anchor text both horizontally and vertically, I added the following:

```
.albumbutton1 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mkwmsd2d/

Comment: Thanks so much, Andy! It worked beautifully. Appreciate all the help!

Comment: @anonimax Glad to help. If you can, I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer. Click the checkmark under this post, on the left.

Comment: Done! I have one more question - I just checked the site on mobile, and the button and text start to overlap. What's the best way to make it responsive?

Comment: @anonimax Have a look at [this example](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/KrxVjL?editors=1100). The key thing here is that the content dictates the height. There is no absolute positioning (so no overlapping on small screens). Also, the image is now a background.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image you want to use as for an input button, you can use the following css

```
.button {
  background-image: url ('/image.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `input` elements, you should use `h1`, `p`, and `a` tags.

You can make "clickable" links to other pages use using the [`a`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) tag.

```
<div class="album">
  <h1>INNER CIRCLE</h1>
  <p>Debut Album Available Now</p>
  <a href="#">LISTEN</a>
</div>
```

All you need to do is replace the # with the url you want it to go to.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/gosh95zb/

Answer (score -1):

Easy one. Just add a trigger on your button.

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com.br');" class="albumbutton1" value="LISTEN">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xqc36Lht/